# Can we get automatic advertisement on the SO latex tagged page?

Tags: feature-request

I'm sure I'm not alone in having `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex` bookmarked. It's the only part of SO I use (I'm not a programmer, so most of the rest is over my head.) It would be nice if a little banner appeared on that page, and at the top of any question tagged `latex` or `tex` that informs SO users of this site's existence. After all, the SO latex tag is going to be less used now that this site exists, I expect...

[Edit: I have asked the same question on SO meta. Now all we can do is wait for public beta...]

Comment: The post on SO meta is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59452/banner-for-tex-and-latex-tags-when-tex-stackexchange-com-goes-public. Maybe people with SO rep could upvote that so that it gets some attention.

Comment: @Caramdir: meta.stackoverflow doesn't share rep with SO, so SO users don't automatically draw more attention on the meta site.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking the same thing.  And maybe a box that pops up when you tag a question `tex` or `latex` on SO that it might be better asked here.
You should probably ask this on meta.stackoverflow.com since its something that will need to be done there.

Answer (score 1):

Not until we are at least in public beta =)

Comment: I meant to mention that.  I think it would be ok once the public beta hits, since if someone is posting to SO, they should already be at least somewhat familiar with the SO concept.