# What should we do (if anything) about [latex] tagged questions in SO?

Tags: discussion

There are still many questions in SO being asked that are tagged [latex]. Should we advertise this site over there? In a comment perhaps? what is the official take on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [our wishes](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237/can-we-get-automatic-advertisement-on-the-so-latex-tagged-pag) and [the official answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59452/banner-for-tex-and-latex-tags-when-tex-stackexchange-com-goes-public/59472#59472).

In short: Nothing while we are in beta.

Comment: The official answer to link to only pertains to whether or not to push users away rom the core site. However other options are possible. one that comes to mind is to duplicate all [latex] and [tex] tagged questions from SO, here. And push-back the answers (to those questions) to stackoverflow. This will be a temporary plug which will make sure that people's questions are answered, and it will supply Tex and friends with more questions.

Comment: Rather than copying answers, I'd just post a comment suggesting people ask here instead. We're in open beta now, so that shouldn't pose any problems.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that those of us who are active on SO should keep an eye on the `latex` and `tex` tags and simply suggest, via comments, that they try their question here.  Nothing heavy, just a suggestion.

If someone spots a question there that makes them think, "I'd really like to know the answer to that." then I see no harm in reposting it over here (with due attribution) and putting a link in a comment to the question on SO.  But I'd recommend only doing it for questions that you feel you are able to make your own question (so that, for example, you would feel no hesitation about accepting a particular answer).